# Why is my JSX element not reducing in size?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have two JSX elements: one is an image and the other is a form. I'm putting them in a span because I want them next to each other, but for some reason, the div container with the form fills up the entire width of the window and renders below the image. When I use inline styling, it reduces the size of the form, but the entire container remains too large. This is what I have:

```
<span>
 <Logo />
 <SearchComponent
  style={{ width: "500px" }}
 />
</span>
```

The code for the form in the component is:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
 {this.getForm()}
 <input
  type="submit"
  value={this.getValue()}
 />
</form>
```

And this is what my output looks like (container highlighted for clarity):

[image]

Comment: The spans are inline, but the div is still a block element. Put `display:inline-block` on it

Answer (score 0):

As [2pha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1550696/2pha) says, divs normally displays as block element. Even you put both component inside the span, it seams you wrapped the `SearchComponent` using `<div>` element.

You can try to add style  `display:inline-block` to your wrapper div as [2pha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1550696/2pha) mentioned in the comment. Otherwise you can try to wrap your component using `<span>` tag instead of `<div>`.

PS: If you you are using bootstrap or some kind of CSS framework you can try to use the grid system to easily put it in the same row and also make it more responsive.

Comment: Adding inline-block didn't help. Looks like using a Bootstrap grid is going to be the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @kreed if you are the one who developed `SearchComponent` component, then you can try to wrap the component using `<span>` tag instead of div.

Comment: I think wrapping SearchComponent in a div is what Babel defaults to. SearchComponent itself is a form. Then when I wrap SearchComponent in a span, it just becomes a div wrapped in a span

Comment: Then you have to use some grid system like bootstrap or other. Or try to use `display: inline` instead if 'display: inline-block`. I don't Know but maybe that will help you.